# Question on linear Algebra in 'Loomis-Shlomo's' book

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Im studying 'Advanced Calculus' in 'Loomis-Shlomo's' book, and got stuck at a question in page 50, question 3.23:

http://www.math.harvard.edu/~shlomo/docs/Advanced_Calculus.pdf

"Suppose T is nilpotent, S commutes with T, $S^{-1}$ exists. $S,T \in Hom (V)$, show that $(S-T)^{-1}$ exists."

Ive tried to substitute I-S+T = x in the formula of question 3.22 and didn't succeed...

Could anyone give a hint?

Answer (score 2):

One trick is to formally compute via power series. Disclaimer: inequalities all come with a grain of salt, the final result is what matters.

Try writing
$$
(S-T)^{-1}=S^{-1}(I-S^{-1}T)^{-1}=\\
S^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty S^{-k}T^{k}
$$
which is in fact the finite sum (this is good), 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^nS^{-k-1}T^k
$$
where $n$ is the order with $T^n=0$.

One may now check this is an inverse directly.

Answer (score 1):

Well, $S-T=S(I-S^{-1}T)$, so if $I-S^{-1}T$ is invertible, then so is $S-T$.

We are given $ST=TS$. Therefore $S^{-1}T=TS^{-1}$. We are also given
$T$ nilpotent, so $T^n=0$ for some $n$. What can we deduce from these
about $S^{-1}T$? About $I-S^{-1}T$?

Comment: Not sure about the last two questions. In any case, given your suggestion, I thoguht: $(I-S^{-1}T)(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} S^{-1}T) =I$ (for the formula given in 3.22, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$, in our case for a finite number of terms).
My question would be then: given $(I-S^{-1}T)(\sum_n S^{-1}T) =I$, can I assume  $(I-S^{-1}T)^{-1}$ exists and $(I-S^{-1}T)^{-1} = (\sum_n S^{-1}T) $?